# rails error - param is missing or the value is empty: buyer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Just starting this app and trying to just get stuff in the DB and I'm getting an error when trying to create a new record in the buyers table.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't find why I'm getting the error.

This is the buyers controller:

```
class BuyersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @buyers = Buyer.all
  end

  def show
    @buyer = Buyer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @buyer = Buyer.new
  end

  def create
    buyer = Buyer.new(buyer_params)
    buyer.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def edit
    @buyer = Buyer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @buyer = Buyer.find(params[:id])

    %w{company name email address city state zip phone_office phone_cell url fund_size founded num_companies min_revenue max_revenue earnings_percent earnings_dollar industry geographic_location}.each do |param_name|
      if params[:buyer][param_name].blank?
        params[:buyer].delete(param_name)
      end
    end

    @buyer.update(buyer_params)
    redirect_to buyers_path
  end

  def destroy
    @buyer = Buyer.find(params[:id])
    @buyer.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
  def buyer_params
    params.require(:buyer).permit(:company, :name, :email, :address,
      :city, :state, :zip, :phone_office, :phone_cell,
      :url, :fund_size, :founded, :num_companies, :min_revenue,
      :max_revenue, :earnings_percent, :earnings_dollar, :industry,
      :geographic_location)
  end
end
```

This is the view where I'm creating the new buyer:

```
<%= form_tag(buyers_path, method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:company, "Company:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:company) %>
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Contact Name:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
  <%= label_tag(:address, "Address:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:address) %>
  <%= label_tag(:city, "City:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:city) %>
  <%= label_tag(:state, "State:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:state) %>
  <%= label_tag(:zip, "Zip:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:zip) %>
  <%= label_tag(:phone_office, "Office Phone:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:phone_office) %>
  <%= label_tag(:phone_cell, "Cell Phone:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:phone_cell) %>
  <%= label_tag(:email, "Email:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:email) %>
  <%= label_tag(:url, "Website:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:url) %>
  <%= label_tag(:fund_size, "Fund Size:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:fund_size) %>
  <%= label_tag(:founded, "Year Founded:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:founded) %>
  <%= label_tag(:num_companies, "Number of Companies:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:num_companies) %>
  <%= label_tag(:min_revenue, "Minimum Revenue:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:min_revenue) %>
  <%= label_tag(:max_revenue, "Maximum Revenue:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:max_revenue) %>
  <%= label_tag(:earnings_percent, "Earnings %:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:earnings_percent) %>
  <%= label_tag(:earnings_dollar, "Earnings $:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:earnings_dollar) %>
  <%= label_tag(:industry, "Industries:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:industry) %>
  <%= label_tag(:geographic_location, "Locations:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:geographic_location) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Create") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some differences when you use form_tag to form_for helper in your view. The form_for helper is designed to adapt to your objects.  It yields an object you use to generate your form elements. One of the differences is that with form_for, when you submit the form, your controller will receive a hash with a key named as your object's class (in your case it's buyer). Like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...=", "buyer"=>{"name"=>"my name"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
```

The form_tag helper is not so customized to your object. And the hash does not have the "buyer" key the way you're using the fields. Then you have a problem when the buyer key is not found here:

```
params.require(:buyer)
```

A solution would be to turn form_tag into form_for, like:

```
<%= form_for(Buyer.new, method: "post") do |form| %>
```

And change your fields and submit to this version:

```
form.text_field(:city)
form.submit("Create")
```